# Constructing a matrix that computes derivatives

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

Consider the subset of functions given by $S = \text{Span}(e^{2t}\, \sin\, 3t, e^{2t}\, \cos\, 3t)$:

Show that the derivatives of $e^{2t}\, \sin\, 3t$ and $e^{2t}\, \cos\, 3t$ are also in $S$ and then use this fact to construct a matrix $D$ that computes derivatives of functions in $S$.

Use the inverse of $D$ to find the integrals of $e^{2t}\, \sin\, 3t$ and $e^{2t}\, \cos\, 3t$.

Comment: Honestly I am stuck with the entire question. I don't know why my teacher gave us this question, it is way above what we are learning right now. I'm pretty sure I can construct with matrix after the answers given and I think I can also simply take the inverse of the matrix and multiply to find the integrals. But I'm not entirely sure of how the matrix was derived.

Comment: The first step is always to understand what the question is asking.  Do you know what span is?  Do you know how to find derivatives?  Can you check if the derivatives are in the span?  Do you know what a linear function is?Do you know how to construct a matrix if you are given a linear function?  Do you understand why the inverse of a matrix is the inverse of the linear function it represents?  But most importantly, do you understand what the question is asking?

Comment: Yes I understand what it is asking and about span and I can calculate the derivatives but I cannot get the concept of the isomorphism taking place here. I only learned isomorphisms from polynomials, not anything like this.

Comment: You don't need to know what an isomorphism is to solve this problem.  It sounds like someone is giving you overly complicated explanations and confusing you.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$
v(t)=e^{2t}\sin 3t \qquad w(t)=e^{2t}\cos 3t
$$
and note that $S=\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span\{v,w\}$. That is, the functions in $S$ are exactly those functions of the form
$$
\lambda_1\cdot v(t)+\lambda_2\cdot w(t)\tag{1}
$$
Differentiating (1) with respect to $t$ gives
$$
(2\lambda_1-3\lambda_2)\cdot v(t)+(3\lambda_1+2\lambda_2)\cdot w(t)
$$
(Check this on your own!)

Thus our differentiation operator $T:S\to S$ is defined on the basis $\beta=\{v,w\}$ by
$$
\begin{array}{rcrcr}
T(v) &=& \color{red}{2}\cdot v  &+& \color{red}{3}\cdot w \\
T(w) &=& \color{blue}{-3}\cdot v &+& \color{blue}{2}\cdot w
\end{array}
$$
The matrix of this linear operator with respect to $\beta$ is
$$
D=
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{2} & \color{blue}{-3} \\
\color{red}{3} & \color{blue}{2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Can you find the inverse of $D$ and finish the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Can we show that the derivatives of those functions are in the span?

- Is $$\frac{d}{dt} e^{2t}\sin 3t = \alpha e^{2t}\sin 3t + \beta e^{2t}\cos 3t$$ for some $\alpha, \beta$?
- Is $$\frac{d}{dt} e^{2t}\cos 3t = \alpha e^{2t}\sin 3t + \beta e^{2t}\cos 3t$$ for some $\alpha, \beta$?

Surely you can apply the product rule to show that it is in fact true.

Step 2: Given that$$\frac{d}{dt} e^{2t}\sin 3t = \alpha e^{2t}\sin 3t + \beta e^{2t}\cos 3t$$ for some $\alpha, \beta$, what does the matrix look like?

We have

$$D\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$D\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -3 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}.$$

Can you construct the matrix D?